# Using this and super() in java

Tags: java

I am wanting to know what `this` and `super` do in the following code. I know that `this` refers to the current object and `super` is used to invoke overridden methods as well invoke a superclasses constructor. But I just can't figure out what the following code does when class `C` is executed.

```
public class A {
    public A(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        System.out.println("A created");
    }
    private int id = 0;
    @Override protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("A finalised");
        super.finalize();
    }
 }

 public class B extends A {
    public B(int id) {
        super(id);
        System.out.println("B created");
    }

 public B() {
    this(42);
    System.out.println("B created with default id 42");
 }
 @Override protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("B finalised");
    super.finalize();
 }
}

 public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new B();
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
 }
```

I am referring mainly to `this(42)`, `super(id)` and `super.finalize()`in class `B`

-Does `this(42)` mean that `B` is instantiated with the value 42, as well as setting `A` id to 42?

-Does `super(id)` pass whatever value that `B` is instantiated with to its superclass which is `A` ? effectively setting the value of `id` in `A` to 42?

-Does `super.finalize()` call the garbage collector on to superclass `A` ?

Comment: See The Java™ Tutorials: [Using the `this` Keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and [Using the Keyword `super`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Comment: Calling #finalize yourself doesn't do anything in relation to the garbage collector, rather that's a method which the jvm calls for you. You should read the documentation on those methods first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does `this(42)` mean that B is instantiated with the value 42, as well as setting `A` `id` to 42?
>
> Does super(id) pass whatever value that B is instantiated with to its superclass which is A ? effectively setting the value of id in A to 42?

This is partially true. `B` *is* instantiated with the value 42, but technically, it sets `B`'s `id` to 42. You never created an `A` object. Inheritance causes everything from the super class to be kind of "copied" to the derived class, so technically, it's the `id` of the `B` object.

Tip: When you see `this(...)` or `super(...)`, just find the constructor that they are referring to, and replace it with what the constructor says. For example:

```
 public B() {
    this(42);
    System.out.println("B created with default id 42");
 }
```

turns into:

```
public B() {
    super(42);                        <-- replaced this(42)
    System.out.println("B created");  <-- replaced this(42)
    System.out.println("B created with default id 42");
}
```

then turns into:

```
public B() {
    super();                        <---\
    this.id = 42;                   <---|
    System.out.println("A created");<---|-----replaced super(42)
    System.out.println("B created");<---/
    System.out.println("B created with default id 42");
}
```

Now you see exactly what happens.

> Does super.finalize() call the garbage collector on to superclass A ?

You don't really need to call `finalize` yourself, the JVM does it for you. And GC is not something that can be called. It just looks for objects with nothing referencing it and collects them at arbitrary times *all by itself*.

Answer (score 0):

Here the explanation of the call sequence:

1. `new B()` calls the no argument constructor of class `B` which calls
2. `this(42)`, the one `int` argument constructor of class `B`, passing in `42` as the argument, which calls
3. `super(id)`, the one `int` argument constructor of class `A`, passing in `42` as the argument, which calls
4. `super()`, the no argument constructor of class `Object`.
5. The constructor of class `A` initializes `A.id` with `42`.
6. All the constructors print fancy strings to the console in the reverse order they were called.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know about this and super
**this**:
1)this always refers to current class object.
2)we can use this to call the same class constructors
3)we can use this to call the same class methods by this.
4)this used to distinguish between the local variables and instance variable of class if they have same name.

**super**:
1)super always refers super class object from sub class
2)we can use super to call the super class constructors
3)we can use super to call the super class methods.
4)super used to refer the super class members if they have access in sub class.

Now coming to your question you have asked about
`this(42), super(id)` and `super.finalize()`in class B

Note: You can call either this() call or super() call from constructor only. Because both this and super calls should be the first statement of constructor. So you can use only one either this call or super call.

```
this(42) :
```

Refers to the same class constructor which takes single argument in your case it is `int` type. So if you call your `new B()` it will goes to B class no arg constructor from there you have written `this(42)` so it will call the B class constructor which takes single argument.

```
super(id) :
```

Similarly you have called super(id) so it will call the super class constructor which takes single argument of that type. If not present it will throw error.

Note:  If you haven't write either this call or super call in constructor by default `super()` will be given by jvm. So it will call the no arg constructor of super class.